# What is the raw_storage_iterator component uses/advantages in C++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I was reading the TC++PL about the [raw_storage_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/raw_storage_iterator/) component. Using this component we get performance benefit as it avoids the assignment(more expensive) and uses copy construction. It looked to me that it should be used in the sequence/container where we could have significant number of elements and hence number of assignment calls can be great impact.

Theoretically its clear and it looked to me that this component is useful for container type classes. However I would like to understand where we should use this component(with practical examples) in bit details to get its performance benefit?

Comment: inb4 "cplusplus.com sucks, don't you dare link to it"; it says right there, it's used so you can be able to use uninitialized memory as the destination for algorithms. Performance should be no better than with a reserved vector with a back inserter iterator. Unless you are writing very low level code, you don't need this iterator.

Comment: @DanielKO a reserved vector with a back inserter iterator has to do size checks at each insert.  The compiler figuring out that the size check is unneeded is relatively unlikely.  You will get good branch prediction on the check, but it will still be less than `raw_storage_iterator` writing.

Comment: By the way, it is deprecated as of C++17 and removed in C++20. So recommended to not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/raw_storage_iterator) there is sample code.

You can allocate aligned blocks of uninitialized memory through a number of mechanisms.  Cppreferences uses [`std::get_temporary_buffer<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) to allocate such a buffer.

You can then make a pointer to these elements.  The pointer's type is a bit misleading, because it isn't a pointer to a **valid** `T`, but rather to a block of memory that is suitable for constructing a `T`.

The `std::raw_storage_iterator` can be populated with that `T*` and told to output to it.  You can then feed that iterator to an algorithm that expects a conventional output iterator, and things go smoothly.

If you tried to do this without the `raw_storage_iterator`, you'd be assigning to a non-constructed `T`, which is undefined behavior.  As an alternative, you could construct the `T`'s before outputting to them -- but that is wasteful, as it constructs the object twice.

The basic idea is to allow use of uninitialized output buffers with near perfect efficiency in standard algorithms.  It isn't something you should be using outside of some serious code microoptimization.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good place to use placement new instead then?
This would make the constructed object go in the reserved space at once. This still requires the programmer to acquire enough space, but it seems like it might be better performance and safety wise.

Comment: @paul this iterator does use placement `new`, just it does it when assigned to.  The raw storage iterator lets you do this as an output to some algorithm from `std` -- some of which you may not want to hand roll.